# properties of identically self-dual matroids

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders, duality-theorems, matroids

I'm dealing with an identically self-dual matroid M on the vertices E=[2N], that is, if B is a basis of M also E-B is a basis of M itself. I need simple combinatorial properties of these, things like the structure of the lattice of flats, properties of the fundamental circuits of the bases, and so on. Nothing major, but before I spend a lot of time on that, does anyone know if I find that systematically done somewhere?